# How to draw lines only between the control points?

Tags: fabricjs

Please guide me in right direction.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumo/8v0a9ono/)
In the example I can draw lines between any two points but would let the user to draw only between control points.

```
drawLine = function drawLine() {
    canvas.on("mouse:down", function (e) {
        console.log("mousedown");
        getMouse(e);

        function getMouse(e) {
            startX = (e.e.clientX - 50);
            startY = (e.e.clientY);
        }
    });
    canvas.on("mouse:up", function (e) {
        console.log("mouseup");
        getMouse(e);

        function getMouse(e) {
            endX = (e.e.clientX - 50);
            endY = (e.e.clientY);
        }
        var line = makeLine([startX, startY, endX, endY]);
        //var line = makeLine([ 150, 225, 450, 225 ]);
        canvas.add(line);
    });
```

Comment: Please make working fiddle and let me know

Comment: Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumo/8v0a9ono/). I am trying to draw the lines only from control point of one rectangle to the other. Thanks for the help..